# What kind of encoding of this string?

Tags: obfuscation, deobfuscation

I find a code like this :

```
main(o,O){while(O=(o++-1)["NdlLQHGFW/"])putchar(O^26+(o|1));}
```

What kind of encoding of that string? and how the decoding process?

Comment: I assume that is the decoding process for it?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen How to encode this string ? `NdlLQHGFW/`